# DD4T-how to use ResolveRichText() extension method?

Tags: 2011, dd4t

I have some links within Rich Text which are not resolving. I found the `ResolveRichText()` extension method, but how can I use these extension methods in our views?

In the below code `sub_copy` is my Rich Text field which consist of links:

```html
@Model.Component.Fields["sub_copy"].ResolveRichText()
```

Do I need to add any namespace for this?

I'm getting the following compilation error:

> CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ResolveRichText' and no extension method 'ResolveRichText' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: What is the error you are getting when you use the `ResolveRichText()` extension method?

Comment: I am getting  compilation error   : CS1061: 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ResolveRichText' and no extension method 'ResolveRichText' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you have the following using in your view?: 
@using DD4T.Mvc.Html

Comment: And you should be using @Model.Component.Fields["sub_copy"].Value.ResolveRichText()

Comment: I have added @using DD4T.Mvc.Html.Also i tried @Model.Component.Fields["sub_copy"].Value.ResolveRichText()   ,giving me the same compilation error message

Answer (score 4):

DD4T comes with a couple of helper methods, which you can integrate in your own DD4T project. You can find the class [here](https://code.google.com/p/dynamic-delivery-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/dotnet/DD4T.Examples/Helpers/RichTextHelper.cs).

Depending on where you put the class, you will possibly need to add a using directive in your Views.

Comment: The class in your link has no extensions methods. Notice the difference with this method signature: public static MvcHtmlString ResolveRichText(this string value)

Comment: I have created a class and added in my view.  I m using the code [code](https://github.com/rainmaker2k/dd4t-sample/blob/master/Sample.Website.Providers/Utils/RichTextHelper.cs). In my view,i have used as var htmlhelper= new HtmlHelperText() @htmlhelper.ResolveRichText(@Model.Component.Fields["sub_copy"].Value).its resolving the links in the richtextfield.But if i am using the same code for any other embedded RTF fields its giving me compilation error of-System.nullrefrence exception:object refrence not set to an instance of an object. The code is not working for embedded RTF fields

Comment: Time to use a debugger for that. ;)

Comment: @Roop - I'm 99% sure we've used the function with embedded fields, could you paste your xml and code into your question?

Comment: @Raimond yes you were right,I changed my method signature to public static MvcHtmlString ResolveRichText().It worked for me.But one thing ,i noticed this issue is only with the embedded richtext fields not with normal richtext fields

Comment: Cool. That makes sense, as on the embedded field you're calling the function through the extension method, so you have to declare it as being one then. :)